# Chrome <audio> playbackRate

Tags: html, google-chrome, playback, html5-audio

I'm trying to use playbackRate attribute of the  element in chrome.
I've created simple markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <audio id="myAudio" preload="metadata" defaultPlaybackRate="1.0" playbackRate="2.0" src="http://path_to_mp3_stream/" autoplay="true"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

But playback stays at its normal rate.
What am I doing wrong?

Google Chrome v20.0.1132.47.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying markup in a following way made it work:

```
<audio id="myplayer" preload="auto" controls="controls">
     <source src="http://path_to_mp3"></source> 
</audio>
<script>
     var player = document.getElementById("myplayer");
     player.playbackRate = 2;
</script>
```

UPD: Looks like there's related [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16502) .

Comment: It took me FOREVER to realize that using jQuery to set `playbackRate` with `attr()` wouldn't work. This worked: `var player = $('#audioPlayer');         player.attr('src', fileUrl);     player[0].playbackRate = $('#playbackRate').val();` The `[0]` was important.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can set the `<audio>`'s `playbackRate` until its `canPlay` event fires, which (along with the browser cache) is likely why your accepted answer worked for you.